# What is the best practice for dealing with 401 in the Javascript client

Tags: google-drive-api

Currently my logic says:-

1. create a gapi.client.HttpRequest object  myRequestObject=gapi.client.request(args)
2. execute that request with myRequestObject.execute(myCallback)
3. if I catch a 401, I refresh the access token. I do this by calling a my own server servlet since I don't like the idea of my JS client
   holding a refresh token.
4. So at this stage my JS client has a new valid access_token, but myRequestObject still holds the stale access_token.

_ I don't want to bubble all the way up to my business logic and create a new HttRequest object. Instead

I just want to resubmit the same object with the new token.

I found that I can poke the header directly with

> myRequestObject.b.headers['Authorization']='Bearer '+newAccessToken;

but is there a more official way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the updated OAuth 2.0 page in the Drive SDK documentation for the JavaScript implementation of the complete flow: https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials

Remember that the JavaScript client library uses the OAuth 2.0 client-side flow which only provides an access token, so you don't have to worry about the client holding a refresh token.

Comment: ah that makes more sense. I must have missed the Javascript examples when I first looked at that page :-(

Comment: We added the JavaScript part recently, you probably looked before then

Comment: I've implemented the JS client side auth as suggested by Claudio. So my step 3 is has changed. However, I still have the issue of how to use the new access token. As my original question stated, I don't want to return to my business logic to retry the API call. So my low level call function pokes the access token into the request object.

Is there any downside to this approach?